# using CSS print media query in an SVG is inconsistent

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, media-queries

I'm trying to hide certain elements in my SVG when printed.

In **Chrome**, when I open the svg directly, everything displays, and when I print preview, the content I intend to hide is hidden successfully via `@media print`.  However, when I open the web page containing this svg (using `<img>`), print preview ignores the print media query, and the content I intended to hide is displayed.

In summary, drag the svg itself into Chrome, print media queries work, open the web page with the svg, print media queries don't work.  Curve ball: IE9 implements the print media query correctly.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="1352px" height="672px" viewBox="0 0 1352 672" enable-background="new 0 0 1352 672"
     xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
<style type="text/css">@media print {#maroonBG {display:none;}}</style>
</defs>
<path id=maroonBG" fill="#722750" d="M1294.262,543.26c0,19.33-15.67,35-35,35H156.321c-19.33,0-35-15.67-35-35V137.784c0-19.33,15.67-35,35-35
    h1102.941c19.33,0,35,15.67,35,35V543.26L1294.262,543.26z"/>
<rect x="81.785" y="176.636" fill="#0000ff" width="387.421" height="124.825"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Either a blink bug or by design as a security feature so that you don't end up printing something entirely different when the image is printed. Try reporting it as a blink bug and see whether they say it's by design or not.

Comment: Very helpful, Robert, thanks.  But where is the best link to do this?  It seems they're only looking for Mac or Linux bugs here: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: I'd try this: http://crbug.com/new